# How do you sum only the integer elements in a list of objects in C# with a loop?

Tags: c#, list, object, integer, type-inference

Consider the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<object> someList = new List<object>();
            someList.Add(1); 
            someList.Add(2); 
            someList.Add("apple"); 
            someList.Add(true);
            someList.Add(3);
        }
```

The list items have not been defined with a data type and contains a boolean, a string, and an integer.  Assuming there are many more list items of varying data types, how do I sum only the integers (such as 1, 2, and 3) from the list of objects using a simple loop or if statement?  I'm just beginning in C#, thank you!

After searching, I've tried something like this, but with no success:

```
            if(!someList.Contains(int))
                List.Add(int);
```

Comment: Would `long.MaxValue` count as an integer? Would `16m` (i.e. `decimal` type containing an integer value) count?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the practical application of such list?

Comment: It's a homework question from class.  I'm not sure of the application, but then again, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: The contrived nature of homework questions makes them nearly impossible to answer well, and especially when the author of the question fails to provide any context that would explain what a good answer would be. `List<object>` is a practically useless type of object; if one insists on using it, then any operation that should be applied only to members of a specific type can be done with the `OfType()` method. See duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you know they are boxed `int` you could use `OfType` and `Sum`

```
var result = someList.OfType<int>().Sum();
```

Or for anything that is a representation of an `int` that would convert to a string representation, you could use  `Sum` with `ToString`, and `int.TryParse`

```
var result = someList.Sum(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out var value) ? value : 0);
```

Or if you like loops

```
var result = 0;
foreach (var value in someList.OfType<int>())
   result += value;

// or 

var result = 0;
foreach (var item in someList)
   if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out var value))
      result += value;
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.OfType(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

[Enumerable.Sum Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netcore-3.1)

> Computes the sum of a sequence of numeric values.

[Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded.